# Using LINQ expressions in Visual Studio's Watch window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a byte[] variable in program, e.g.:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[] { 0xF0, 0x0F };
```

When debugging this program, I wanted to display the byte array content as individual hexadecimal values inside Visual Studio's Watch window.

So I tried to use the following LINQ expression in the Watch Window, without success:

```
myByteArray.Select(value => value.ToString("X2")).ToArray()
```

Watch window's error message:

> error CS1061: 'byte[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and
>   no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type
>   'byte[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Does anyone know if there is a way to use LINQ expressions in Visual Studio's Watch window without installing third-party extensions?

I'm using VS2017 15.6.6 at this moment.

Edit: A screenshot of this issue...

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Do you have the required `using` directives in your code (`System.Linq`)?

Comment: Have you tried using the Immediate Window?

Comment: @Bigiansen : I've got the same error message in the immediate window.

Comment: This article explains what's going on:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debugging-issues-with-linq-7f8704136072?sk=38cd481056b23191dc5d64c95c18d293

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and found the following:

It seems the watch window uses the namespaces you referenced (via `using`) in your code.

If you don't use linq (and `System.Linq` namespace) in the code file, the watch window cannot find the extensions.

If you have a `using System.Linq;` and **use** something from that namespace in your code, the watch window will find and execute the linq extensions. (If you don't use anything from `System.Linq` the reference is optimized away, so this assembly is not loaded at runtime and the debugger can't use it).

Comment: I've updated my post with a screenshot: even adding the using System.Linq statement, this issue persists. Any clue on that?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp yes, updated my answer, you don't only need the `using`, but have to make sure something from that assembly is used, otherwise it's not loaded at runtime and the debugger can't use it.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp And it seems you have to use the namespace _before_ the breakpoint, so the assembly is already loaded when you hit it.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, thank you! Although I'm not happy with that outcome ;-)

Comment: Isn't there any way to force the "using System.Linq" statement not to be "optimized"?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: Btw it's not enough to have code that uses System.Linq.Enumerable extension methods. The code that uses those methods needs to be called during the program's execution. eg. if you have a class that calls LINQ extension methods, but the main class never calls that class, then System.Core.dll will be included during compilation but will not be accessible, you'll need to use Assembly.Load("System.Core") to actually be able to access the LINQ extension methods.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't have a 'using System.Linq' statement in the code, you can still use Linq queries by calling the extension methods manually:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(collection, x=>x.Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Try to add the following: (Its working on my test)

```
> using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
```

Comment: That's why you are probably using LINQ expressions elsewhere in the same file. Try the same in a fresh new class. The using statements will be greyed out, because you are not using LINQ anywhere in your file.  In this case, LINQ is not available in the Watch window AND in the Immediate window.